# Error using pyrax module on OSX

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pyrax

I'm using the ansible rax.py script for my inventory. The problem I'm experiencing has nothing to do with ansible but with pyrax or pbr.

I've taken the following steps:

```
sudo pip install pyrax
python
>>> import pyrax
```

And then I get:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pbr/packaging.py", line 870, in get_version
raise Exception("Versioning for this project requires either an sdist"
Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. Are you sure that git is installed?
```

According to some github issues one should install pbr separately to get around this issue. I've done this without any luck.

```
pip show pbr
---
Name: pbr
Version: 0.10.0
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires: pip

pip show python-novaclient
---
Name: python-novaclient
Version: 2.19.0
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires: requests, iso8601, python-keystoneclient, Babel, oslo.utils, six, simplejson, pbr, PrettyTable, argparse
```

I'm using python 2.7.5 and not virtualenv. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Barry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following seem to have gotten things into order:

```
pip install --upgrade distribute
```

After various version conflicts and all some helpful staff member saved me.

Comment: Legend, this has been pissing me off for hours!

Comment: I've posted this to avoid these kind of problems in the future: https://medium.com/@barry_botha/using-vagrant-to-run-your-ansible-playbooks-2d7616a5d99a Its about using Vagrant to run your Ansible Playbooks.